# Sample variance: degree of freedom argument

Tags: sampling, variance

In sample variance we divide by n-1 and not n. I know a couple of arguments for this - one is that this is sort of a normalization to ensure that the expected value of sample variance is equal to population variance (I calculated this mathematically and it is sort of a good argument) and the other argument is an intuitive one where we argue that the outliers in a population i.e. "Samples" with extreme values actually have a very low probability of getting selected in our Sample and hence our sample is more closer to mean than it should be scaled up.
But a few days back our stats teacher gave a new argument related to degrees of freedom. Just to be sure I checked and got this definition for degrees of freedom: the number of variables we can vary without changing the constraints of the system. But my question is in Sample Variance we actually have n+1 variables - n independent random variables and one mean of these. And therefore I believe that I can vary all these n random variables and get the mean accordingly or vary n-1 random variable AND the mean and get the nth random variable - either way i will get n degrees of freedom.
What is the flaw in this argument because my teacher argued that there would be n-1 independent variables and n-1 degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 1):

Estimates of statistical parameters can be based upon different amounts of information or data. The number of independent pieces of information that go into the estimate of a parameter are called the degrees of freedom. In general, the degrees of freedom of an estimate of a parameter are equal to the number of independent scores that go into the estimate minus the number of parameters used as intermediate steps in the estimation of the parameter itself (i.e. the sample variance has N-1 degrees of freedom, since it is computed from N random scores minus the only 1 parameter estimated as intermediate step, which is the sample mean).

-Wikipedia

The sample mean is an estimated parameter, not a random variable. Constructing the mean as a linear combination of your existing variables does not add to the dimensionality of your system (I'm not sure if you have any prerequisite linear algebra).

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Oh i am sorry to include mean as "random variable" but what i meant was that removing a vector from the basis and adding in the substitute vector such that new combination is linearly independent would be a new basis which would again contain n elements...

Comment: But I think I might get what you are saying...

Comment: Is it something like this...the definition of degree of freedom is something like i will take a "sample" of required information and then the number of variables i can change while maintaining the intermediate parameters is the required "independent" pieces of information...That is to say In variance example, I would first select a sample and then calculate its mean i.e. the constraint added and then see how many variables I can change...which would I think be consistent with the definition you gave...Am i correct here or there some flaws?

Comment: @Govindsarangautum  You are exactly right. to keep the basis of n elements with your new "mean" added, you have to remove one of the independent variables.